# How can I "hide" a website using jQuery or javascript AND require a password?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm creating a wedding website for a family member and want a very simple way for people to enter a password before it reveals the site. It doesn't need to be secure.

I was thinking I could have a white "layer" above the website with a simple password form on it (the website will load underneath it). Then, when the password is entered, the white layer disappears and the website appears.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Don't use client-side scripting for website security. JavaScript can be disabled by the client which renders it utterly pointless.

Comment: Help you with what? I can say yes what you want to do is possible, though this isn't exactly the right place to ask someone to write code for you.

Comment: @both ... he said it doesn't have to be secure, he obviously doesn't care about that.

Comment: @Kevin: Indeed, then the whole exercise is entirely pointless, and I'm left wondering what the point of the exercise is?

Comment: @DavidThomas : Sometimes you just need to convince Grandma that her photos aren't public so she doesn't whine about it.

Comment: I agree, but posting that it's not going to be secure after he clearly stated it doesn't need to be secure is also pointless. :-)

Comment: It's not really an exercise. I was just hoping someone could help me.

Comment: This could be done with a simple submit handler on the form that checks whether the password input value is x, and if it is x, then hide the white layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example.

**HTML**

```
<div class="page">
    HERE IS MY PAGE
</div>
<div class="cover">
    HERE IS THE COVER
</div>
```

**JavaScript** *(jQuery)*

```
$('.cover').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $(this).remove();    
    });   
});
```

**CSS**

```
.page{
    background-color:green;
    height:200px;
}
.cover{
    background-color:yellow;
    height:200px;
    z-index:200;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    float:left;
    width:100%;

}
```

[See it on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/LRhHx/8/)

Comment: Perfect! Now to figure out how to add a nice-looking password box. I've made forms before, so I imagine it should be pretty similar.

Answer (score 0):

Uh.. since you've said it doesn't need to be secure (*shudders*), you'll be able to get away with......

Wrapping everything that pertains to your website in some container, let's say a `div`, throw a class on it `'main-content'`. You have several options as to how you would like to hide it:

1. CSS display:none;
2. inline style: display:none;
3. height:0px;

In addition to your `'main-content'`, create a div on a similar level and give it an identifier, i.e. class of `'login-content'`. Leave this untouched (i.e. visible).

When the DOM loads your `login-content` should be visible, whereas the main-content won't be.

When the user has 'successfully logged in', revert the styles. i.e. `main-content` -> `display:block;`, `height:100%`, whatever..

Comment: Ah, sounds like a good concept. So it's actually hiding the page and using javascript to display it again.

Could you point me to where I could learn to code this in javascript?

Comment: Yeah; this will do if you have all the content within that page. Personally I hate suggesting this, though. Alternatively, you could load the website content (i.e. load the HTML into `main-content`) after the login (thus preventing them from viewing source, or modifying the dom with dev tools etc). It won't be secure, but it'll be a bit better.

Comment: You know, I could probably just have a log in form as a separate page which then redirects to the website.

Comment: of course. there are numerous ways to go about this.. just thought I'd answer since all you got was "f*** that"

Answer (score 0):

With the help of js you can do this:

```
var password;

var pass1="1234567";

password=prompt('Enter your password',' ');

if (password==pass1) {
  $('body').show();
} else  {
  $('body').hide();
}
```

This is the source if you want more information:
http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jpass.htm

Comment: Nice! This is pretty close to what I was thinking. I'll try and figure out how to use a stylized box instead of an alert box.